# Let $A$ be nonempty set, check whether $\subseteq$ is a partial order on $P(A)$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

*[How can I show that this is a partial order?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/371536/how-can-i-show-that-this-is-a-partial-order) did not really help because I got confused*

I found it to be
*Transitive since if $A\subseteq A$ and $A\subseteq B$ then $A\subseteq B$
*Antisymmetric since $A\subseteq A$ and $A\subseteq A$ so $A=A$
*Reflective since $A\subseteq A$ and $A\subseteq A$

But I am not sure if my way of solving this or the answer is whether true or not, can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 0):

You are suppose to consider elements $B,C,D \in P(A)$ and verify those properties.

For example for transitive, you are suppose to check

if $B \subseteq C$ and $C \subseteq D$, whether we have $B \subseteq D$.

Comment: So I have to say A⊆B and B⊆C then A⊆C?

Comment: well, try to avoid using the notation $A$ again because in this question, $A$ is a special set that is used to construct $P(A)$.